# array merge with duplicates php

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I want to merge two arrays with duplicates 
For example,
    $n1 = array(0=>'foo', 1=>'bar', 2=>'baz');
    $n2 = array(0=>'lorem', 1=>'ipsum', 2=>'foo');
Results should be,

```
$result = array(0=>'foo', 1=>'bar', 2=>'baz',3=>'lorem', 4=>'ipsum', 5=>'foo');
```

I there any **predefined function** available in PHP

Comment: -1 I do not see the effort put into this.

Answer (score 3):

how about [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)? It does exactly what you need.

```
$array = array_merge($n1, $n2);
```