# turn 2 array into one array

Tags: php, database

In PHP there is two array:

```
$x = array( "a" => "0123", "b" => "1234", "c" => "0123");
$y = array( "a" => "3210", "b" => "1234", "d" => "0123");
```

i wish to get the result in one array like this:

```
// right
Array
(
[a] => 0123
[b] => 1234
[c] => 0123
[a] => 3210
[d] => 0123
)
```

I tried with array_merge($x, $y):

```
// wrong    
Array
(
[a] => 3210
[b] => 1234
[c] => 0123
)
```

It happen cause there is old database and new database, i am getting both value from both database. If value from both database ist exactly equal, then it needed only on value like this:

`[b] => 1234`

Please is there some solution in PHP-Code?

Comment: You can't have 2 indexes with the same name (`a` in this case) as stated => `[a] => 0123
[b] => 1234
[c] => 0123
[a] => 3210
[d] => 0123` And array_merge gives this result (with the `d` ) => `["a"]=>
  string(4) "3210"
  ["b"]=>
  string(4) "1234"
  ["c"]=>
  string(4) "0123"
  ["d"]=>
  string(4) "0123"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging arrays with the same keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881443/merging-arrays-with-the-same-keys)

Comment: This won't happen, key name in an array is unique, it impossible you have two key named 'a' in an array.

Comment: if the key 'a' repeat two time with different values, then consider 'a'=>value1, value2], this way you can have both different values

Answer (score 2):

Becuase of you cant get same keys use  [array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php).
It will make muldimensional arrays for same keys.

```
$ar1 = array("color" => array("favorite" => "red"), 5);

$ar2 = array(10, "color" => array("favorite" => "green", "blue"));

$result = array_merge_recursive($ar1, $ar2);
[color] => Array
    (
        [favorite] => Array
            (
                [0] => red
                [1] => green
            )

        [0] => blue
    )

[0] => 5
[1] => 10
```

Comment: You could use the OP's actual data, might be more expresive

Answer (score 0):

Arrays cannot have duplicate keys, if keeping the keys isn't important to you then the following would work fine:

This code is pulled straight from the PHP array_merge documentation.

```
<?php
$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [color] => green
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => a
    [3] => b
    [shape] => trapezoid
    [4] => 4
)
```

Also see: [array merge with duplicates php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858864/array-merge-with-duplicates-php)